# Die2Nite hoarding defensive items

Tags: die2nite

Today everyone in my town is going to die because a zombie spike on day 6. There were 7 defensive items in the bank so i took 4 and put it in my chest, if i were to take the other 3 defensive items so nobody could take them and kept it would it raise my chances of getting last man standing so nobody else could get it?

Comment: I haven't played this in a while, but most likely you'll be shunned at some point and all your defense items will be put back into the bank for doing this.

Answer (score 2):

No because with less objects in the bank to protect the town from zombies, the more zombies that will get in and the greater the chance you'll be killed. When defense objects are in the bank they give a better defense rating than when they're in your house (about %50 the amount of defense), which makes it important to leave the defensive objects in the bank for everyone to benefit from... including you!

Answer (score 1):

I've died before with more house defenses than anyone else. I know the game states that you are the last chosen if you have more defenses, but I've experienced the opposite (dying while others w/ less defenses survive).

Your best bet is to keep ALL the defensive items in the bank, no matter what.

Comment: Having more personal defense improves your chances of surviving, but it certainly doesn't guarantee it.  The zombies that get through are randomly distributed between the remaining citizens, and you die if the ones distributed to you are higher than your personal defense.